# Why does VS2010 give syntax errors when syntax is correct?

Tags: c, visual-c++, boolean, visual-c++-2010

I am having a problem with VS2010 (and VS2008) giving my a great list of syntax errors. However, the syntax is indeed correct. Here is a small example;

I have the following code block inside a .h file

```
// Prototype Declarations
LIST*   createList     (int (*compare) (void*, void*));
LIST*   destroyList    (LIST* plist);
int     addNode      (LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr);
bool    removeNode      (LIST* pList, void* keyPtr, void** dataOutPtr);
bool    searchList      (LIST* pList, void* pArgu, void** pDataOut);
bool    retrieveNode    (LIST* pList, void* pArgu, void** dataOutPtr);
bool    traverse        (LIST* pList, int fromWhere, void** dataOutPtr);
int     listCount    (LIST* pList);
bool    isListEmpty     (LIST* pList);
bool    isListFull      (LIST* pList);
```

LIST is a typedef'd struct, FYI. All of these function declarations appear to be correct syntax. Yet, when attempting to build, I get the following syntax errors starting at the first bool function, going down the list.

> Error 2   error C2059: syntax error : ';'

I'm failing to see where the problem lies. Again, this is just a small example. I also receive syntax errors such as the following

```
bool found;
```

> Error 29  error C2065: 'bool' : undeclared identifier

I'm truly at a lost on this one. The code posted here isn't my own, it's from a data structures book, but again it looks correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: .c or .cc/.cpp file extension? On the file including the .h, that is.

Comment: check the lines around the code that is giving you issues, and, check the header files (they often give me trouble).

Comment: I can't see any syntax errors either in this extract of code. One source of error I can see is the absence of the definition of `LIST` prior to the prototype declarations. Is it being declared or the file in which it is declared is being included before `createList`'s definition?

Comment: Try to reduce the code to smallest sample that generates these errors and post here (if by doing this you don't get the answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bool` is not a fundamental type in C.

Visual C++ only implements C90, which has no `bool` type.  C99 added support for `bool` via the `<stdbool.h>` header, but Visual C++ does not support this.

You should either use `int` or create your own typedef for `bool`.

Comment: It should be noted that `_Bool` is a fundamental type in the C language and `bool` can be obtained via `stdbool.h`, except that MSVC does not support the C language...

Comment: This is it, thank you sir! I didn't know Visual C++ used C90, I assumed C99.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file extension of the file including that header.

Visual Studio will automatically compile .c files as C rather than C++ if you don't tell it to do any differently (in the project settings).

Visual Studio's "C" support is... interesting - to my understanding it is in fact C89 rather than C99, and you can't just flick a switch to get C99. C89/C99 aside, bool is not a builtin type in C.

You can rename all your files to .cpp to compile them as C++, or modify the project settings to force compilation as C++ for every .c/.cpp/.cc file in the project.