# Errors C2059 and C2061 in C language

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does VS2010 give syntax errors when syntax is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671312/why-does-vs2010-give-syntax-errors-when-syntax-is-correct)

I'm trying to develop a kind of Windows 32 service in C language, using Visual Studio 2010.

I created a new project, and inserted .c files :

- main.c
- service.c
- misc.c

I also have two header files :

- myerrors.h
- my.h

Here's the code I have (be aware that it's just a draft).

main.c :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "my.h"
#include "myerrors.h"

static int parse_args(int ac, char **av)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (++i < ac)
        if (strcmp(av[i], "-i") && !InstallMyService())
            return false;
        else if (strcmp(av[i], "-d") && !UninstallMyService())
            return false;
        else if (strcmp(av[i], "-p"))
            if (!av[i + 1])
                return false;
            else
            {
                if (!InsertPathInRegistry(av[i + 1]))
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
        else
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    HANDLE hLogFile;

    if ((hLogFile = CreateFile(LOG_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        aff_error(CANT_CREATE_FILE);    
    if (ac > 1)
    {
        if (!parse_args(ac, av))
        {
            aff_error(BAD_ARGUMENTS);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = {{DC_SERVICE_NAME, ServiceMain}, {NULL, NULL}};
        StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable);
    }
    getchar();
    if (!CloseHandle(hLogFile))
        aff_error(CLOSE_FILE_FAILED);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

misc.c :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my.h"
#include "myerrors.h"

void aff_error(char *error_str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", error_str);
}

bool InsertPathInRegistry(char *path)
{
    printf("LOG: Inserting %s as ", path);
}

void WriteInLogFile(HANDLE hLogFile, char *log_string)
{
    printf("WriteInLogFile function");
}
```

service.c :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "my.h"

bool InstallMyService()
{
    return true;
}

bool UninstallMyService()
{
    return true;
}

void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode)
{

}

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD ac, LPTSTR *av)
{

}
```

My headers are just some function declarations and macros such as :

```
# define DC_SERVICE_NAME    "MyService"

/* MISC functions */

void aff_error(char *error_str);
```

my.h

```
#ifndef _MY_H_
# define _MY_H_

#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

/* Macros */

# define LOG_FILE_PATH      "c:\\my_log_file.txt"
# define DC_SERVICE_NAME    "MyService"

/* MISC functions */

void aff_error(char *error_str);

/* SERVICE functions */

void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD ac, LPTSTR *av);
bool InstallMyService();
bool UninstallMyService();
bool InsertPathInRegistry(char *path);
void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode);

#endif /*!MY_H_ */
```

While trying to compile the project, i got some weird errors :

```
my.h(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'InstallMyService'
my.h(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
my.h(19): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Or :

```
my.h(21): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'InsertPathInRegistry'
my.h(21): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
my.h(21): error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

I checked on some forums that says those errors are commonly errors with includes badly placed, but I don't really know in this case, I don't think I made mistakes with includes...

Can anyone illuminate me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Care to show us `my.h` ?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Ah, missed that. For that matter, it's `_Bool` rather than `bool` iirc.

Comment: i edited my post to show `my.h` but it seems that i'll have my answer in your comments :)

Comment: @BillyONeal:  Yes.  `_Bool` is the name of the new C99 fundamental boolean type.  `<stdbool.h>` defines `bool` as a synonym of `_Bool`.

Comment: Seems like @JamesMcNellis got it :-)

Comment: Thank you @JamesMcNellis, I didn't see this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bool` is not a data type in ANSI C.  It is a data type in the C99 version of the language, *only if `<stdbool.h>` is included*, but Visual Studio does not support C99, only C89 (C99 also adds the `_Bool` data type, which can be used without including any headers).

I suggest you replace `bool` with another type such as `int`, or use a `typedef` to alias it with `int` or `unsigned char` or something.

Comment: I replaced all `bool` with `int` and it works great ! Thank you !