# Simple way to execute C program without IDE

Tags: c, exe

I am new to C. What is the most simple way to execute a C program without an IDE?

I created my first C program und it runs flawlessly using my IDE Netbeans on Mac OS X. Now I need to make that program be "executable without IDE on Windows".

Also the requirement is only "Windows", no specific version. Which means I might have to support XP, Vista, 7, 8.

What is the most simple way to do so?

Comment: Do you mean to *compile* it without an IDE?  Once it's compiled, you can *run* it on any computer just by double-clicking the .exe file.

Comment: Yes then I mean compile it. How can I compile my program to .exe?

Comment: Your IDE compiles the program (producing an .exe file) every time you click the Build button or run the program from within the IDE.

Comment: I found a unix executable under `dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/bfs` that runs in Terminal. How can I create a .exe for Windows?

Comment: @Indianer: If you've taken dependencies on the Mac OSX functions then you're program won't compile under Windows. You should only be using standard C library and other cross-platform libraries for the program to run across platforms.

Comment: So, do I understand right, you want to *cross-compile* on Mac, with Windows XP as cross compilation target (so it should run on later Windowses as well)?

Comment: You can try and use an online compiler, for example http://www.onlinecompiler.net/ . Pros: no installation required. Cons: eventually becomes a bit tedious when you often need it; and unless you fully trust the service, you may want to virusscan the executable immediately after downloading it.

Comment: If you can get a Windows installation for doing the Windows build, then one fairly simple way would be to use Qt SDK for your project. Its toolchains (not sure what it has for OSX, but for Windows you can use the included MinGW GNU toolchain, or separately installed free versions of MSVC) and IDE (Qt Creator) support also non-Qt plain C projects.

Comment: Yes what I wanted was cross compiling. Now, I will try to build on Windows, hoping my Mac OS C code does not break.

Comment: Online compiling fails with error. Whats wrong with `enum bool {false,true};` and later declaring `enum bool readFiles();` Error says: `error: expected identifier before 'bool' ` and `error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token `

Comment: Apparently `bool`, `true` and `false` are already defined in onlinecompiler's version of `stdio.h`. You are likely to run into the same issue when using a regular 'offline' compiler for Windows. Easiest solution is to just use the existing `bool` type (not preceded by `enum`).

Comment: Using just `bool` or `BOOL` on a regular compiler on Windows gives me errors C2061 and C2059 on all the functions using bool. How to fix it

Comment: SO is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671312/why-does-vs2010-give-syntax-errors-when-syntax-is-correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you have built your app, it is a program you can run outside the IDE.  You just need to find it.  :)  In NetBeans this will usually be under your project directory in a subdirectory called "dist".  There will be an executable file in there which you can copy out to wherever you want.

Comment: I have just build it, but I cannot find a .exe file. I am using Mac OS, do I have to build on Windows?

Comment: No, sorry I said exe when I should have said executable.  You should be able to find the program NetBeans built by looking in the Project Properties, perhaps under Linker settings.

Comment: Yes I found it `dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/bfs` but that does not run under Windows, as I built under Mac OS right?

Comment: Right, so if you want to run on Windows you need to build on Windows.  You can't (at least, not easily) build C programs for Windows machines  where the build machine runs Mac OS.  If you really want to try, it's called cross-compiling and some tools are here: http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_win32

Comment: Thanks, I will try to build on Windows, hoping my Mac OS C code does not break.

Answer (score 1):

Download MinGW here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files
and install it.
Then go to cmd (In Windows 8 - Windows key+R and type cmd in the window opened. In Windows 7 - search >> run >> cmd).
After installing it and entering cmd type in the Command Prompt window (CMD) `cd C:/MinGW/bin` (when MinGW is on C drive which is the default path). After doing so type the following command: `gcc -o X.exe Y.c` when X is the name of the output file (what name you want the .exe file to be and Y is the name of the C file that must be inside of the BIN folder (C:/MinGW/bin by default). It should be compiled smoothly if it compiled in your IDE and then the .exe file would be in the BIN folder named X.exe (when X is what you typed in the CMD). Afterwards, you can close your CMD and do with the .exe file whatever you like.